# How can a user access a .NET Core Web API server without first obtaining a token from Identity Server 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, token, identityserver4

### What do I have?

- Authentication Server using Identity Server 4
- .NET 6.0 Web API
- Angular frontend
  I use the `implicit` grant type and flow in order to authenticate all front-end requests to the backend and Identity Server 4. All working correctly. The front end issues itself a token from IS4 via the correct username and password and uses the access token to authenticate itself to the backend.

### The problem?

There is an unusual scenario where a client needs to access the .NET Core Web API without having to request a token from Identity Server 4 before that. In other words, the user needs to authorize themselves and access the data using only one request, without first obtaining a token from Identity Server 4. The client doesn't want to fire two requests, one to obtain a token and another to get the data.
How can I create client-specific tokens that don't expire and validate them from the .NET Core Web API using Identity Server 4? A lot of integrations use this approach where a client has a unique "key" that is included in the `Authorization` header directly. But how can this be implemented with IS4?

I am aware that this approach is less secure than using access tokens because the special token is not tied to a specific user and can be used by anyone who knows the token value. Therefore, one should use this approach carefully and one should take appropriate security measures to protect the special token value.

Comment: Use a controller an make a route anonymous which does require credentials.

Comment: Yes that's the easy part. I can create a custom Authorize filter, that will be separate from the Authorize I use elswhere. The thing is how to set up the Identity Server 4 client in the correct way and also how to validate the token received in the custom authorize filter from the headers. I guess I have to make a request to IS4 to validate it. Those are my questions.

Comment: If you just  want to let the client directly access the Web API without accessing the identity server, the one solution is you could create a new authentication schema which allow cookie authentication, the client could directly access your web api by using the username and password.

Comment: I see what you mean. The thing is the client is gonna be a server, so it's supposed to be server-to-server communication. I will create the authentication schema, this part I can do. The thing is I want all client credentials and details to stay on the Identity Server. So when I am in the authentication schema and get authorize header, how do I validate it towards Identity Server? How can I issue the client the Authorization header value, which token value should not expire and be client specific for him? My question is more about how to set up the IS4 and how to validate it in the Web API.